# Replace lambda expression with equivalent code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

Can I replace a lambda expression with an equivalent expression using IntelliJ IDEA refactoring. Thanks.

```
public class StateOwner {
    public void addStateListener(StateChangeListener listener) { ... }
}

..
StateOwner stateOwner = new StateOwner();

stateOwner.addStateListener(
    (oldState, newState) -> System.out.println("State changed")
);
```

Can I have IntelliJ IDEA replace the lambda expression part with

```
stateOwner.addStateListener(new StateChangeListener() {

    public void onStateChange(State oldState, State newState) {
        System.out.println("State changed")
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question... IntelliJ offers this as an option when you hover over the arrow of the lamdba

Comment: Take a look here, you do need IntelliJ 2017.1

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/migrating-to-java-8.html#d178614e264

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on your hot-key setting. But if you use default, you can try lead cursor on lambda narrow or lamdba arguments, then **alt + Enter**, then choose "replace lambda with anonymous class"

Comment: Option + Enter on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

It offers that in the same way as it offers to turn your code into a lambda. 
Make sure you have a fairly late version.